# Загрузка и выгрузка файлов welleng python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне необходимо интегрировать библиотеку *welleng* в программу. Загрузка и выгрузка данных должна происходить через файл Экселя, но я не знаю *в каком формате* они должны быть и *как именно вызывать сохранение* полученных данных. Может ли кто-нибудь, пожалуйста, подсказать с этим или привести пример?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пока ничего непонятно. Может это вам как-то поможет https://jonnymaserati.github.io/welleng/_modules/welleng/io

Comment: welleng берёт данные из csv, проводит расчёты и выводит график. Я чекал гит, понял, что работа с координатами графика проводится в файле Survey, но я всё равно не понимаю, как должен выглядеть csv файл, чтобы он брал оттуда данные, а в конце выводил обработанную информацию.